# 403 Forbidden when trying to query AWS ElasticSearch cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-jest

I'm having issues performing requests using jest to an AWS ElasticSearch cluster v5.3.

Reason is:

`The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method. Consult the service documentation for details`

I am using windows 10 with java 11, spring boot 2, webflux, jest and the aws http request signer that they point to in their documentation.

I've checked and doubled checked the access and secret keys of the IAM user. I also added policies for the IAM user of full control over the cluster, still the 403 message.

Removing or adding the Content-Length header yields the same error.

Not sure where to go from here.

Any help would be appreciated. 
Thx

Answer (score 0):

So from I discovered, is that the network issue had something to do with the corporate proxy. I created a tunnel between my laptop and the ElasticSearch cluster, removed the proxy from the http client used by jest, and things work smoothly now.

I wasn't able to figure out exactly how the proxy affected the request signature though, but I'll stick with the tunnel solution.